# Can Flat ii Function as a Dominant and Pre Dominant?

Tags: chords, chord-theory

In the key of C, the chord Db(b) is an N6, pre dominant chord. However when reading about tritone substitution Db7 can also be a dominant substitution.

Is it the inversion and the added 7 that makes this “same” chord function as both pre-dominant and dominant substitution?

Comment: Using 'flat ii' presumes it's minor. Then the question wording presumes it's major. Help!

Comment: Seems like a pretty cut and dry typo to me. OP might be working from a source that uses that "Berklee notation" where the capitalization of the roman numeral doesn't matter (normally they use all caps) and you specify `II-7` if you mean minor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`N6` and `II♭7` are not the same chord and do not share their tonal function.

`II♭7` includes the 4<sup>th</sup> and the 7<sup>th</sup> of the key (the same tritone as `V7`), and can therefore act as the dominant of `I`. While `N6` (a `II♭maj` triad) does not include the 7<sup>th</sup> leading tone.

Moreover, in the classical language, `N6` is usually found in first inversion preparing the dominant of `V`, while `II♭7` is usually found in its fundamental position resolving to `I`.

> `N6` is seen by some as a "minor subdominant" (despite being a major chord), since it includes the 4<sup>th</sup> and the b6<sup>th</sup> of the key (which are the notes shared by subdominants in the minor key).

Comment: In the second paragraph it says the N6 does not include the 4th or the 7th, but in the last paragraph it says the N6 includes the 4th and the b6th.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Sorry, I meant to say that it did not include both, i.e. the tritone. I have clarified this in the comment.

Answer (score 3):

*Tritone substitution* is a jazz concept and because the jazz concept is concerned with the tritone of `TI` and `FA` being in both a dominant seventh chord and its tritone substitution, both chords are considered to have dominant function normally resolving to a tonic chord.

"Classical" harmony has a concept called *augmented sixth chords* which have some similarity to jazz tritone substitution, but the origin of augmented sixth chords starts with raising the root of a `iv6` chord, for example in `C` minor that would be a bass of `A♭` and the raised root of `F♯`, which forms and augmented sixth, and the chord resolve with those two tones moving in contrary motion to the dominant scale degree `G`, being a chord that resolves to a dominant augmented sixth chords are considered *pre-dominant* or *subdominant* regarding function.

`N6` is the *Neapolitan six chord*, which in its textbook appearance is a `iio` chord with a lowered root. In `C` minor it would be a `D♭` major triad, and the chord is normally in first inversion. `N6` normally resolves to the dominant chord and so functions as a *pre-dominant* or *subdominant* chord.

One of the augmented sixth chord types is the "German" augmented sixth, which can be enharmonically respelled to display the intervals of a dominant seventh chord. `N6` being a major triad also has the interval structure of a dominant triad. Again, the normal function of those chord is *subdominant*, but the chords are sometimes used with an *irregular* resolution where the chords resolve as if they were dominants. Examples in `C` minor would be a German augmented sixth chord, enharmonically spelled to `A♭7` resolving to a tonic `D♭` chord, or a `N6`, `D♭` major triad resolving to a tonic `G♭` chord. These irregular resolution change the chord functions from subdominant to dominant and can be used to modulate to distant keys.

So, it is possible for these chords to function either in the normal subdominant role, or in certain cases to switch to a dominant function. The devil is in the details of the various forms of these chords and their exact resolution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the other responses get to the heart of the matter, which is that **these two uses of `bII` come from very different musical practices.** So, the answer to “Can `bII` function as a dominant and subdominant?” is **yes, in the right context.**

The **Neapolitan chord** (that is, `bII` used with a subdominant function) is associated with Classical music; the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neapolitan_chord) provides examples from the baroque, classical, and romantic periods. As Wikipedia notes,

> Neapolitan most commonly occurs in first inversion so that it is notated either as ♭II6 or N6 and normally referred to as a Neapolitan sixth chord

but it doesn't *have* to be in first inversion be analyzed as `N`.

`bII` with a dominant function is an example of **tritone substitution,** a technique generally associated with jazz and bebop but also found in a variety of popular styles. Typically, a minor 7th will be added to this chord to complete the tritone from `V7`, as Nuno Andre mentions in his answer.

Arguably, the 7th should be present, yielding `bII7`, for it to really “count” as a tritone substitution. However, performance practice sometimes employs `bII` in a dominant context even without the added 7. In such cases, you could argue that this is still an “implicit” tritone substitution, which works because of our familiarity with `bII7` in similar contexts. Our ear doesn't need the 7th to recognize the chord's dominant function, for the same reason we don't need every `V` to be a `V7`. Alternatively, you could argue that `bII - I` is an example of planar motion or [parallel harmony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_harmony) because each tone resolves down by a half step.

Comment: Heavy metal spams i - bII - i, but due to its rampant usage of other chord progressions that lack the dominant such as i - VI - VII - i, I do not consider that genre's use of bII to have any dominant function.

Comment: I agree, in a vamp context I would be hesitant to speak of chord "functions" at all since it's really the harmonic rhythm that drives the sense of tension and release rather than the particular relationships among the chords. The point is that the language we use to describe music should reflect both the immediate harmonic context as well as the genre.

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks additional to Nuno’s answer:

The N6 chord is specifically subdominant because it merely replaces the fifth of the minor iv by the minor 6th. Note that contrary to the *sixte ajoutée* the fifth is actually replaced. But what happens in a IIb7 chord is that the sixth is added, and we do in fact get the diminished fifth.

In the regular case the fifth of the iv chord is the tonic, which therefore prepares the lead tone, which defines the subdominant character. Now, if you replace this tonic by the diminished tonic this will enharmonically sound like the leading tone, giving it a dominant function. In fact if you spell

Db - F - Ab - Cb

as

Db - F - Ab - B

and reorder and extend a different root note

[G] - B - Db - F - Ab

you see you get a V7 b5 b9 chord.

Of course you can embed a N6 chord in the same setting, but the reading would by far not be as obvious. But since this chord does have both the upper leading tone (bII) and the secondary leading tone (bVI) the resolution works quite decently. What does *not* work well is reading IIb7 as predominant. But commonly you’d find these sort of chords on the bVI instead of bII, functioning as a secondary dominant. Classic progression there would be

vi7 - i46 - V4-3 - i